# Which constructor does this semantics call?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a construct of string:

```
string s {"Hello world!"};
```

And string class has the following constructor that I think might be bound to:

**From char pointer/array:**

```
string (const char* s);
```

**From initializer_list:**

```
string (initializer_list<char> il);
```

At first I thought it will be calling `initializer_list` because the parameters are braced. Then I saw the initializer_list takes an argument of `char` but that was a string.

Then I realize the `{""}` can be implicitly converted to `char[]` thus it might call the first constructor... In this case, is a pair of parentheses automatically added around the list(e.g. like `({""})`)?

So which constructor does it actually call?

---

How about this:

```
double d1 (100);
double d2 {100};
```

Are they the same?

Assume string also has a constructor like `string(initializer_list<string>)`, then which one will it call?

Comment: This has been asked a lot, but it's uniform initialization of the first constructor.

Comment: You could've tried yourself: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/OX5N9l).

Comment: To invoke the constructor taking an `initializer_list<char>` type you need to use this - `std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c'};`

Comment: I just realized it actually may call `string(string&& s)` by C++11...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string(const char*)
```

The `{}` syntax does not necessarily imply `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @texasbruce The answer is the same. It's uniform initialization.

Comment: If a class (assume string) also has a constructor of `string(initializer_list<string&&>)`, which one will it call?

Comment: @texasbruce it'll call `T(initializer_list<string>)` then. Edit: you can't have list of rvalue references.

Comment: @jrok Because I thought I put the literal which is temporary (like can be bound to rvalue reference)?

Comment: You didn't pass a temporary, you passed a string literal. Yes, there's a temporary somewhere when converting to `std::string`, but that has little to do with template parameter. There's some compiler magic behind `initializer_list`, in particular, it's not specified how and where the elements are stored.

Comment: Then what does it imply? You should make this clear to the OP and the other readers.

Comment: @0x499602D2: It means just what I said... a definition of an object that uses curly braces may call a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list` or any other constructor, depending on what goes inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 8):

In C++11, curly braces `{}` are used for uniform initialization.  Any object that can be initialized can be initialized with curly braces.  Preference is given to constructors that take `initializer_list<T>`, so if a curly-brace initialization could match more than one constructor and one of them takes an `initializer_list`, that will be selected.  However, if no `initializer_list` constructors match, the other constructors are also considered.

For example:

```
vector<int> two_elems{5,10}; // A vector containing two elements
vector<int> five_elems(5,10); // A vector containing five elements
vector<int> five_elems_also{10,10,10,10,10}; // Equivalent to the above
```

In your example, you're initializing a `string` with a `char const[13]`.  This would match `initializer_list<char const*>`, if `string` had such a constructor, but it doesn't match `initializer_list<char>`.  So the parameter is instead matched against the other constructors, and the constructor taking `char const*` is the best match.

Note that because of the ambiguity, it's probably best not to initialize containers (such as `vector`, `set`, `list`, or even `string`) using brace initialization unless you intend to use the `initializer_list` constructors.  For example, there's no way to call `vector<size_t>`'s constructor that takes `size_t, T` using brace-initialization, since that argument list will also match the `initializer_list` constructor.  As another example:

```
vector<char const*> vec_of_strs{ 5, 0 }; // Creates a vector holding *5* nullptrs
vector<unsigned> vec_of_nums{ 5, 0 }; // Creates a vector holding *2* numbers
```

It's not immediately obvious that the two lines above are calling very different constructors, and if the type of one were changed to the other during maintenance (or the code occurred in a template), programmers may be very surprised at the sudden behavior change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... It is rude to change the right answer so I upvoted :) 10 points and 15 points are close...

Comment: @texasbruce It's not rude at all. If you feel it deserves the tick, by all means, change it.

Comment: @jrok, I put "5" in on purpose.

Comment: @Adam sorry, rolled back. I saw parentheses there for some reason.

Comment: @jrok Well honestly David's answer is more direct to my question so I won't change it lol. But this is a good answer too